# Formula field on opp using created date, record types, profiles, and multiple stage names

Tags: opportunity, formula-field, picklist, record-type, createddate

This formula works for all my requirement except the underlined part:

```
IF( AND(RecordType.Name = 'Solutions', 
        DATEVALUE(Account.CreatedDate) <= TODAY() - 10, 
        CreatedBy.Profile.Name = "Perkins Access Standard User", 
        ISPICKVAL( StageName , 'Won Completed'))  ,
   "existing customer", 
   "new customer")
```

I need a formula that marks customer "existing customer" if- record type is "Solutions. Created date (on account) was created more than 10 days from today, Created by a user with the Perkins Access Standard User profile, and that has an opportunity stage of "Won completed" or "Won in Progress" or "Won Pending start". Customers that don't meet that criteria should be marked "New Customer"

But I'm having trouble adding the opportunities that have a stage of Won in Progress" or "Won Pending start".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `OR()` formula around the picklist values you're interested in including.

```
    ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'Won Completed'))  ,
```

becomes

```
OR(ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'Won Completed'),
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'SomeOtherStageToInclude'),
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'YetAnotherStage'),
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'AndSoOnAndSoOn')),
```

This will evaluate to `true` if any of the arguments is `true`.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say, but I think I still didn't do it right. This is what I have-

Comment: IF( AND(RecordType.Name = 'Solutions', DATEVALUE(Account.CreatedDate) <= TODAY() - 10, CreatedBy.Profile.Name = "Perkins Access Standard User", OR(ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'Won Completed'),
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'Won in Progress'),
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , 'Won Pending start')
"existing customer", "new customer")))

Comment: and it is giving me this error- Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Comment: You're just missing a parenthesis after the third record type.

Comment: it is still giving me the same error- Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Comment: The only things contained in your `OR()` parentheses should be `ISPICKVAL()` functions. Those are Boolean-valued. If you're seeing that error, you have something in your function that doesn't go there.